# No message found under code for locale 'pl_PL'

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

When I try to validate a form I'm getting NoSuchMessageExceptions for messageSource.getMessage(...) method invokations.

Here is the validation method:

```
@Override
    public Event validateUserCompany(NewUserCompanyForm userCompanyForm,MessageContext messageContext) {
        MessageBuilder error = new MessageBuilder().error();
        boolean eMailIsUsed=userCompanyDao.ifEmailIsUsed(userCompanyForm.getUserName());
        boolean companyNameIsUsed=userCompanyDao.ifCompanyNameIsUsed(userCompanyForm.getCompanyName());
        if(!eMailIsUsed && !companyNameIsUsed){
            return new EventFactorySupport().success(this);
        }else if(eMailIsUsed){
            error.source("userName");
            error.defaultText(messageSource.getMessage("message.userName.isUsed",null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
            messageContext.addMessage(error.build());
        }else if(companyNameIsUsed){
            error.source("companyName");
            error.defaultText(messageSource.getMessage("message.companyName.isUsed",null, LocaleContextHolder.getLocale()));
            messageContext.addMessage(error.build());
        }
        return new EventFactorySupport().error(this);
    }
```

The exception that I get is:

```
org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'message.userName.isUsed' for locale 'pl_PL'.
```

Here is the content of the message.properties file:

```
message.userName.isUsed= Message1.
message.companyName.isUsed= Message2.
```

Here is the MessageSource bean:

```
@Bean
    public MessageSource messageSource(){
        ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource=new ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource();
        messageSource.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
        messageSource.setBasenames("/messages/messages");
        return messageSource;
    }
```

Messages directory is in the path /src/main/resources.

What's weird is that when I'm invoking messageSource.getMessage(...) in the testing class everything goes fine.

Here is the method in the testing class:

```
@Test
    public void messageSourceTest(){
        Assert.assertNotNull(messageSource.getMessage("message.companyName.isUsed",null, Locale.forLanguageTag("pl_PL")));
        Assert.assertNotNull(messageSource.getMessage("message.userName.isUsed",null, Locale.forLanguageTag("pl_PL")));
        Assert.assertNotNull(messageSource.getMessage("message.companyName.isUsed",null, Locale.ENGLISH));
        Assert.assertNotNull(messageSource.getMessage("message.userName.isUsed",null, Locale.ENGLISH));
    }
```

I can't find a reason why the method invokation in the test doesn't generate an exception, but the same method invokation in the other part of the system does. The validateUserCompany() method in the Service works properly as well in the testing class.

I'm invoking the method that generates an exception using Spring Webflow.

Comment: You are providing contents of `message.properties` file. At the same moment in your code you have `messageSource.setBasenames("/messages/messages")`. Pay attention to the last `s`. Is this a typo?

Comment: Sorry, it's a typo in stackoverflow post. Names on project are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving the Resource Bundle messages (containing message.properties) from resources directory to webapp solved the issue.